# Can I get saml-token as string?

Tags: spring-saml

I am using spring-security-saml2 1.0.0.RELEASE.
It works well and pretty good for me.

But New requirement is rised. I need saml-token as string.

can I get the saml-token as string. I find saml-token in log. 
But how to get the saml-token as string format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, I've just added a new chapter to the Spring SAML manual which addresses this issue:

> **Authentication assertion**
>
> Assertion  used  to  authenticate  user  is  stored  in  the 
>   *SAMLCredential* object  under  property *authenticationAssertion*. By
>   default the original content (DOM) of the assertion is discarded and
>   system only keeps an unmarshalled version which might slightly differ
>   from the original, e.g. in white-spaces. In order to instruct Spring
>   SAML to keep the assertion in the original form (keep its DOM) set
>   property *releaseDOM* to *false* on bean *WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl*.
>
> Assertion can be serialized to String using the following call:
>
> `XMLHelper.nodeToString(SAMLUtil.marshallMessage(credential.getAuthenticationAssertion()))`