# how to get SAMLResponse from request

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml, opensaml

Can any body help me how to capture the SAMLResponse.I am using Spring SAML.

I have used below  snipet in the custom filter where the authenticatinSuccesshandler sends. but getting a null. 
String responseMessage = httpServletRequest.getParameter("SAMLResponse");

please advice me.

Answer (score 4):

The typical use-case is to get access to the SAML assertion and this can be achieved as is described [in this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512753/can-i-get-saml-token-as-string). The assertion is also available in the `Authentication` object, you can load it using the following piece of code, for example from your authentication success handler:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
SAMLCredential credential = (SAMLCredential) authentication.getCredentials();
String assertion = XMLHelper.nodeToString(SAMLUtil.marshallMessage(credential.getAuthenticationAssertion();
```

The assertion is stored as an unmarshalled java object which doesn't keep all the details as received. In case you need to keep the value in exactly the same format as received (including white spaces, ...), make sure to set `releaseDOM` to `false` on `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl` bean.

You can access the `SAML Response` object e.g. by overriding classes in bean `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl`, where it's being processed inside the `SAMLMessageContext` object.